# Command to display free memory in percentage

Tags: shell-script, awk

I want to display free memory as a percentage. I'm pretty sure that I'm not displaying the free memory but the used one. Or am I wrong?

```
mem=`free -m | awk 'NR ==2{printf $3,$2,$3*100/$2}'`
echo $mem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
free | awk '/^Mem/ { a=(($3-$7)/$2 * 100); print a"% of Memory used"  }'
3.43143% of Memory used

free | awk '/^Mem/ { a=(($4+$7)/$2 * 100); print a"% of Memory free"  }'
96.5662% of Memory free

free | awk '/^Mem/ { a=(($7)/$2 * 100); print a"% of Memory cached"  }'
80.4204% of Memory cached
```

Note: crosscheck the values with `glances`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the amount of free memory as a percentage, Divide Column 4 (free) by Column 2 (total) and multiply the result by 100.

For example:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ free | awk '/^Mem/ { printf("free: %.2f %\n", $4/$2 * 100.0) }'
free: 97.32 %
```

If you want to show the amount used, you can divide column 3 (used) by column 2 (total) and multiply the result by 100.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ free | awk '/^Mem/ { printf("Used: %.2f %\n", $3/$2 * 100.0) }'
Used: 2.75 %
```

You can use %g for rounding to a specified number of significant digits.

For example, if you only want a whole number, and not a floating point value, you can change the number of floating point digits specified to 0 (zero).  In this first example %.2f means 2 floating point values.

And here is an example with zero floating point values:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ free | awk '/^Mem/ { printf("Used: %.0f %\n", $3/$2 * 100.0) }'
Used: 3 %
```

This is also answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/linux-command-for-percentage-of-memory-that-is-free